# Operator with three const?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

In the book [C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B%20design%20patterns%20and%20derivatives%20pricing&oq=C%2B%2B%20desi&aqs=chrome.1.0l2j69i57j0j35i39j0.3198j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) by Mark Joshi at 
p.75, he writes:

```
const T* const operator->() const
{
    return DataPtr;
}
```

The first `const` means that it returns a const object, and the last `const` means that the operator is not allowed to modify the object on which it is called. But what about the second `const`? What is its role?

Comment: The second `const` is redundant. It doesn't matter whether a scalar object returned by value is `const` or not. It's an rvalue that can't be modified anyway. Further, an idiomatic smart pointer would return a plain `T*` - see e.g. [`shared_ptr::operator->`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the duplicate!